# query in mysql to perform the not in function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query in mysql to filter out the vendorids' which are not in vendorids of the userid = 1 but they are present in  vendorids of the userid = 5 but I am not getting the correct answer the query is below

```
select vendorid  
from rating_table 
where (userid = 5) not in (select vendorid from rating_table where userid = 1)  
order by vendorid asc;
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `vendorid` is not in the subquery result

```
SELECT vendorid 
FROM rating_table 
WHERE (userid = 5)
AND vendorid NOT IN 
(
    SELECT 
        vendorid 
    FROM rating_table 
    WHERE userid = 1
) 
ORDER BY vendorid ASC;
```